# Why function will not change variable?

Tags: c, function, return, double

In this code I seem to get zero, I'm not too familiar with as to why I can't change the variable length with the function I created. Any help could be useful.

```
     #include <stdio.h>
double get_length(double a);
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    double length = 0;
    get_length(length);
    printf("%lf", length);
    return 0;
}
double get_length(double a)
{
    printf("What is the rectangle's length?\n");
    scanf("%lf", &a);
    return a;
}
```

When it prints it returns 0.0000

Comment: Works as intended: local variables/function arguments do not survive the function's return.

Comment: A common misunderstanding of functions in C. calling `get_length(x);` has no effect on value of `x`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not storing the return value. Change:

```
get_length(length);
```

to:

```
length = get_length(length);
```

There's no need to pass `length` when you do this.

The other way to do it is to pass an address:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void get_length(double * a);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    double length = 0;
    get_length(&length);
    printf("%f", length);
    return 0;
}

void get_length(double * a) {
    printf("What is the rectangle's length?\n");
    scanf("%lf", a);
}
```

Note that `%f`, not `%lf`, is the correct format specifier for a `double` in `printf()`. Using `%lf` is correct for `scanf()`, however.

Comment: By the way, the original `double get_length(double a)` is kinda funny: it essentially asks the caller to initialize the function's local variable `double a`.

Comment: @Joker_vD: Yes, saves one single line of source code at the expense of much weirdness.

Answer (score 3):

C is "pass-by-value", which means the value is actually copied in.  So changing the value by using the reference doesn't actually change the original reference.

There are two ways around this:

1) store to a local value and then capture the return value:

```
length = get_length()
...
double get_length()
{
    double a;
    printf("What is the rectangle's length?\n");
    scanf("%lf", &a);
    return a;
}
```

2) pass a pointer:

```
get_length(&length)
...
double get_length(double *length)
{
    printf("What is the rectangle's length?\n");
    scanf("%lf", length);
}
```