# double changes to 0 when it returns to main function

Tags: c, variables, return, double

Can anybody help me figure out why does the variable's value change to 0 when it returns to the main function ? I'm new to C and I have no idea what i'm doing

[image: Screenshot of the source code]

Comment: Please post the text of your source code, not a link to an image.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour]. Pictures of code are not much loved here, for several reasons.

Comment: Note that the `double a` parameter for function `select` is not taking the quite different variable `double a` in `main` by reference, but by value, so you pass a *copy* of the (uninitialised) variable defined in `main`. This might be clearer to you if you rename the function parameter (and its use) as say `double aval`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why function will not change variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19483459/why-function-will-not-change-variable)

Answer (score 0):

When you return a value from a function you have to assign to your var, it does not change your in parameters in the main function so do this:

```
a = select();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a function in C language remember to assign them.
You gave select function but didn't assigned return value to any value try to assign any variable so that the return value will be assigned to that variable

```
int value(int a,int b)
{
    int c=a,d=b,e;
    e=c+d;
    return(e);
}
void main()
{
    int n;
    clrscr();
    n=value(24,54);
    printf("value is %d",n);
    getch();
}
```

output

```
value is 78
```

here I have assigned n to the result so that I got the output has 78 :D

Answer (score 0):

The problem is ‘double a’ in the ‘add’ function is a local varaible, so the change will not been showed in the main function.

You can put ‘double a’ before function ‘select’(let ‘double a’ become a global varaible), or use `a=select(a,b)` to correct the problem.