# How to fix problem counting letters,symbols,numbers in string using function to check number

Tags: c

I want to count letters,numbers,symbols using function password Seems like it doesn't count out numbers correctly because i get 0 for every printf in the end

```
#include <stdio.h>
void password(char * str[],int together,int numbers,int symbols,int i,int uppercase,int lowercase);
int main()
{
    char str[100];
    int together, numbers, symbols, i,uppercase,lowercase;

        together = numbers = symbols = i = uppercase = lowercase = 0;

    printf("password : ");
    gets(&str);
    printf(" %s", str);
    password(&str,together,numbers,symbols,i,uppercase,lowercase);
    printf("Number of letters = %d\n", together);
    printf("number uppercase  = %d\n", uppercase);
    printf("Number lowecase  = %d\n", lowercase);
    printf("numbers = %d\n", numbers);
    printf("Simboli = %d", symbols);
if (together >= 8 && numbers >= 2){
    printf("\nPassword is correct");
}else{
    printf("\nPassword isn't correct");
}
    return 0;
}
void password(char * str[],int together,int numbers,int symbols,int i,int uppercase,int lowercase){
     while(*str[i]!='\0')
    {
        if((*str[i]>='a' && *str[i]<='z') || (*str[i]>='A' && *str[i]<='Z'))
        {
            together++;
        }
        else if(*str[i]>='0' && *str[i]<='9')
        {
            numbers++;
        }
        else if(*str[i] >= 'A' && *str[i] <= 'Z') {
         uppercase++;
        }
        else if(*str[i] >= 'a' && *str[i] <= 'z'){
            lowercase++;
        }
        else
        {
            symbols++;
        }

        i++;
    }
}
```

I get zeroes for every number,letter & symbol program runs without any error I tried changing some stuff but I am currently learning C so it is hard for me!

Comment: Arguments are passed by value. This means that if you change them in the function they only change locally. You need to pass a pointer to them and then change the value through that.

Comment: Can you give me an example in my code or something

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why function will not change variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19483459/why-function-will-not-change-variable)

Comment: I tried changing str[] to *str[] and then editing it in gets(&str) but still getting that zeroes

Comment: That’s not the variable you’re trying to *return* a value in

Comment: So pretty much i need to get that string in main and then get it into void password by using pointers * and & not sure how it works It is my homework so I am pretty new to this

Comment: We stopped using `gets` over 20 years ago, so you need a new source of learning. In addition, you are using it wrong, which is why you get compiler messages there.

Comment: `if(*str[i] >= 'A' && *str[i] <= 'Z')` is not guaranteed to work.  Only the digits `'0'` through `'9'` are guaranteed to be represented consecutively.  You should use `isupper()` (and `islower()` to detect lower-case letters.)  See [**5.2.1 Character sets** of the C standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.1).

Comment: Oh I never heard from my teacher about isupper() and islower() can you give me more details about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few points : 1) There is no need to pass i as argument since you can get the length of your string with `strlen` from `string.h` (which returns a `size_t` type and not an `int`). 2) You passed your arguments as value, which means that they'll only change locally to your function. 3) Don't use the gets function that is not safe, you may want to use `fgets` or `scanf`.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void password(char *str, int *together, int *numbers, int *symbols, int *uppercase, int *lowercase){
    for(size_t i=0; i<strlen(str); i++){
        if(str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9') (*numbers)++;
        if(str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z') (*uppercase)++;
        if(str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z') (*lowercase)++;
        if(str[i] >= '!' && str[i] <= '/') (*symbols)++;
    }
    *together = (*uppercase) + (*lowercase);
}

int main(void){

    char str[100] = "Pa$$w0/2d";
    int together = 0;
    int numbers = 0;
    int symbols = 0;
    int uppercase = 0;
    int lowercase = 0;

    password(str, &together, &numbers, &symbols, &uppercase, &lowercase);
    printf("Letters = %d\n", together);
    printf("Uppercase  = %d\n", uppercase);
    printf("Lowercase = %d\n", lowercase);
    printf("Numbers = %d\n", numbers);
    printf("Symbols = %d\n", symbols)

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help! This helped me alot of understanding that I can use strlen() for it I am trying to learn stuff from other people and from online tutorials. I removed ="Pa$$w0/2d' and replaced it with scanf(" %s",&str).

Comment: @MarinSpudić Hope you understand better now. Also, you'll get a warning by doing `scanf("%s", &str)` if you first initialize your `str` by `char str[100]` : %s expects a `char *` when you give it a `char **`. So you have to remove the `&`. (You can see the warnings when compiling with gcc by giving the flags -Wall -Wextra)